# Uart receives correct Bytes but in chaotic order

Tags: c, atmel, atmelstudio

Using Atmel studio 7, with STK600 and 32UC3C MCU

I'm pulling my hair over this.
I'm sending strings of a variable size over UART once every 5 seconds. The String consists of one letter as opcode, then two chars are following that tell the lenght of the following datastring (without the zero, there is never a zero at the end of any of those strings). In most cases the string will be 3 chars in size, because it has no data ("p00").

After investigation I found out that what supposed to be "p00" was in fact "0p0" or "00p" or (only at first try after restarting the micro "p00"). I looked it up in the memory view of the debugger. Then I started hTerm and confirmed that the data was in fact "p00". So after a while hTerm showed me "p00p00p00p00p00p00p00..." while the memory of my circular uart buffer reads "p000p000p0p000p0p000p0p0..."

edit: Actually "0p0" and "00p" are alternating.

The baud rate is 9600. In the past I was only sending single letters. So everything was running well.

This is the code of the Receiver Interrupt:
I tried different variations in code that were all doing the same in a different way. But all of them showed the exact same behavior.

lastWebCMDWritePtr is a uint8_t* type and so is lastWebCMDRingstartPtr. 
lastWebCMDRingRXLen is a uint8_t type.

```
__attribute__((__interrupt__))
void UartISR_forWebserver()
{
    *(lastWebCMDWritePtr++) = (uint8_t)((&AVR32_USART0)->rhr & 0x1ff);
    lastWebCMDRingRXLen++;
    if(lastWebCMDWritePtr - lastWebCMDRingstartPtr > lastWebCMDRingBufferSIZE)
    {
        lastWebCMDWritePtr = lastWebCMDRingstartPtr;
    }
// Variation 2:
//  advanceFifo((uint8_t)((&AVR32_USART0)->rhr & 0x1ff));

// Variation 3:
//  if(usart_read_char(&AVR32_USART0, getReadPointer()) == USART_RX_ERROR)
//  {
//      usart_reset_status(&AVR32_USART0);
//  }
//      

};
```

I welcome any of your ideas and advices.

Regarts Someo

P.S. I put the Atmel studio tag in case this has something to do with the myriad of debugger bugs of AS.

Comment: `if(lastWebCMDWritePtr - lastWebCMDRingstartPtr > lastWebCMDRingBufferSIZE)` ---->  `if(lastWebCMDWritePtr - lastWebCMDRingstartPtr > lastWebCMDRingBufferSIZE-1)`

Comment: Thanks, but thats not the bug I#m looking for I guess... ;)

Comment: Well, did you try it? Your code access the circular buffer out of bounds of 1 so your queue, staring from base address, will be "shifted" by one value.

Comment: The _strings_ sent have no terminating identifier, either as a null character or `'\n'`, etc.  The recipient does not know where one _string_ begins and another _string_ ends.

Comment: Minor: @LPs good idea can be written as `if(lastWebCMDWritePtr - lastWebCMDRingstartPtr >= lastWebCMDRingBufferSIZE)`.

Comment: The recipient does know, because the lenght of the string is transmitted after the opcode character. However on UART Level of communication this also isnt an issue because there is only a transmission of one character at a time. @LPs yep I did and it wasn't the fault. Although I wished for it.

Comment: @chux Yes, basically , for me, is more clear at first look using the form I posted ;)

Comment: It is inherent in *serial* communication that it is impossible to receive data in a different order than it was sent.  Supposing that sender and receiver agree on the protocol parameters, the only alternatives are that you send the data in a different order than you think, or that the receiver scrambles the data after receipt.

Comment: Yes thats what I'm thinking too, so I checked the transmission with an external program and it appears to be correct. The Error must be in the Interrupt or the datahandling. But I fail to catch it.

Comment: Did you check the specification? You say that `lastWebCMDWritePtr` is `uint8_t`, but on pl011 for instance, it should be a 32 bits pointer. Also, this address could be marked as `volatile` because its semantic is not a memory (read(write(v)) != v). Did you check the generated code?

Comment: Be careful with "The recipient does know, because the length of the string is transmitted after the opcode character. "  The length of the string is whatever length was transmitted.  sending appended data does not _force_ the prior length to match.  IOWs, what happens if the "length of the string is transmitted after the opcode character" is incorrectly computed?  What happens if a byte is lost in transmission?  A simple oops on CRLF to LF calculation can easily mess things up.  I recommend each message begin/end with a special character that is not otherwise used, such as `<` and `>`.

Comment: Did you try using [`usart_read_char`](http://simplemachines.it/martin/mizar32/1.6.0-AT32UC3/DRIVERS/USART/USART_EXAMPLE/DOC/html/a00003.html#b73fc2f42bd6fe66c03d598b0158436d) function to read a character from UART buffer instead of directly accessing `rhr`? If there was a communication error, the content of `rhr` may not valid.

Comment: Are your FIFO variables declared `volatile`?

Answer (score 0):

For a complete picture you would have to show where and how **lastWebCMDWritePtr**, **lastWebCMDRingRXLen**, **lastWebCMDRingstartPtr** and **lastWebCMDRingBufferSIZE** are used elsewhere (on the consuming side)

Also I would first try a simpler ISR with no dependencies to other software modules to exclude a hardware resp. register handling problem.

Approach:

```
#define USART_DEBUG
#define DEBUG_BUF_SIZE 30

__attribute__((__interrupt__))
void UartISR_forWebserver()
{ 
  uint8_t rec_byte;
#ifdef USART_DEBUG  
  static volatile uint8_t usart_debug_buf[DEBUG_BUF_SIZE]; //circular buffer for debugging
  static volatile int usart_debug_buf_index = 0;
#endif      

  rec_byte = (uint8_t)((&AVR32_USART0)->rhr & 0x1ff);

#ifdef USART_DEBUG  
  usart_debug_buf_index = usart_debug_buf_index % DEBUG_BUF_SIZE; 
  usart_debug_buf[usart_debug_buf_index] = rec_byte;
  usart_debug_buf_index++

  if (!(usart_debug_buf_index < DEBUG_BUF_SIZE)) {
    usart_debug_buf_index = 0; //candidate for a breakpoint to see what happened in the past
  }
#endif
  //uart_recfifo_enqueue(rec_byte);

};
```

Comment: I found it out now, it was a hardware failure. After switching the MCU with a new one it worked as intended. I wish I thought of that earlier.